# absorption length of thermal neutrons in a medium

Tags: particle-physics, collision, absorption

My book states that
$$N(x)=N_0\cdot e^{n\cdot \sigma \cdot x}$$
for $n$ absorbing particles per volume element with a cross section $\sigma$.

Can somebody explain where this comes from?

Comment: What book are you getting this from?

Comment: It's a book from Bogdan Povh

Comment: Hint: thermal neutrons are on a drunkard's walk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a volume $\Delta x$ (I'm assuming linear density here), the number of particles that get absorbed is going to be the number of particles in a given volume times the probability that an absorption occurs.  This is just the density times the cross section, $n_0 \sigma$.  Thus, the change in the number of particles crossing through that volume is the product of the probability that a neutron will got absorbed with the total number of neutrons in the volume
\begin{equation}
N_f = N_i - N_i ~n_0 \sigma ~\Delta x
\end{equation}
for a one-dimensional problem.  In the $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ limit, this becomes the differential equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{d N}{d x} = - n_0 \sigma ~ N
\end{equation}
whose solution is just the exponential decay.